# How split the time in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to split the time for having the hours, the minutes, and the second on a list.
But with the datetime module I can't.
This is my code :

```py
heure = datetime.now().time()
heure = heure.split(":")
print(heure)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just need to call `.hour` on the `datetime.now()`.

Comment: Please read the documentation of datetime. Clearly you haven't even read the first part, copy pasting the answers below won't do you much good.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method called `datetime.strftime`, which also uses `datetime` like the method you tried to use. We change the string input to an integer using `int()`.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt   # Import datetime module

now = dt.now()

# Using strftime to get the string into a global variable
year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")
day = now.strftime("%d")
hour = now.strftime("%H")
minute = now.strftime("%M")
second = now.strftime("%S")
microseconds = now.strftime("%f")

# Turning the variables into integers
year = int(year)
month = int(month)
day = int(day)
hour = int(hour)
minute = int(minute)
second = int(second)
microseconds = int(microseconds)

# Putting the variables into a list
heure = [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microseconds]

print(heure)
```

**Indexes of the heure list**

---

Index 0: Year

---

Index 1: Month

---

Index 2: Day

---

Index 3: Hour

---

Index 4: Minute

---

Index 5: Seconds

---

Index 6: Microseconds (1/1 000 000th of a second)

---

> The only problem is that the time is in UTC, sadly, I do NOT know how to convert it using `datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

`heure` is a `datetime.time` object, not a string.  It already splits out the various components of the time as properties.  Do:

```
>>> hms = [heure.hour, heure.minute, heure.second]
>>> hms
[8, 9, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `heure` to string with the `str()` and then split it.

```
heure = datetime.now().time()
heure = str(heure).split(":")
print(heure)
```